# Cordova error: Undefined is not a function

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

To compile Jade files in my android app, I add Jade plugin from https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-jade.

But after adding plugin to my Cordova project I am getting this error on running my project:

> Undefined is not a function

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: May be you missing js file of that plugin to add in your index page.

Comment: please add some ode?? what u have tried so far..